# REST: update a collection with one "compressed" representation

Tags: rest

I have a collection that contains a lot of resources and all of these resources contain some equal attributes:

```
GET  /api/collection

Answer:  
{ "items": [  
   { "id":1,
     "Status":"Value",
     ...
   },
   { "id":2,
     "Status":"Value",
     ...
   }
   ...
 ]
}
```

I need to update the "Status"-attribute of every resource. To do this, I think there are two typical ways: 1. Following a hyperlink to the actual resource and update every resource on its own or 2. Update the whole collection.

For reasons of usability (e.g. manual exploration of the api) I want to do this a little bit more compact by just saying which new value should be set for the "status"-attribute. This are my ideas and questions for every proposal:

1. Introducing a **new query parameter**, e.g.
   `PUT /api/collection?setAll=true
   { "Status": "NewValue" }`
   I think this is actually not a real *"query"*-parameter, since GET-requests are not allowed. Is such a construct permitted, where GET is allowed on the resource-URL `GET /api/collection` but it is forbidden to do a GET when just adding a query parameter? Does REST permit to transmit a completely other representation than the one that is given back when requesting the resource (single object vs. a list of objects)?
2. Introducing a **new resource**, e.g.
   `PUT /api/collection/setAll
   { "Status": "NewValue" }`
   This new resource is somehow like a function that is executed and I saw some apis that do things like this. I know that this is not a good practice, but seemingly sometimes not avoidable. Another point is: is it allowed/reasonable to have a resource that is not *requestable* with GET?
3. Using an **other media type**, e.g.
   `PUT /api/collection
   Content-Type: application/vnd.example.collectionCompact+json
   { "Status": "NewValue" }`
   Same question as in 1.: Does REST permit to transmit an other structure of the resource than the one that is given back when requesting the resource?
4. Introducing a **new method**, e.g.
   `PUTALL /api/collection
   { "Status": "NewValue" }`
   Is this the best *restful* solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
PATCH /api/collection { "Status": "NewValue" }
```

the PATCH method is for partial updates. Don't bother with the URI, it does not matter. What matters is defining a custom [link relation](http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) for the bulk update, so your client will understand what the link means.

Try to use a standard MIME type, like HAL or JSON-LD instead of creating custom MIME types. By HAL you'll need custom MIME types by the requests only. By JSON-LD and Hydra you won't need custom MIME types at all.

Comment: Yes, I think, this is the way to go. One further suggestion: If one does a _PATCH_ against the whole collection, one should do it in the way you suggested; and if one wants to filter, a query parameter should be used e.g. `PATCH /api/collection/?region=apac`.

Comment: A single resource (in this the collection) can have multiple URIs. So you can always define a new URL with a new query parameter or a path parameter. `PATCH /api/collection/region:apac/`. It does not really matter which one you choose. According to the URI standard the hierarchical params should go into the path, but hierarchical can be a very subjective term. Just to mention you have to send links to the client, and annotate those links with semantics, e.g. link relation.

Answer (score 0):

1) or 2) are both feasible solutions. Passing parameters in the URL is perfectly fine and it's widely used.

As a consumer of the service I would like #2 better, as it feels more natural and more intuitive if I'm looking at the resources and trying to figure out what to do.

Thinking there's a resource if you want to update a collection, where you `PUT` the collection to update it, you know, business as usual. But if I want to do a quick update, there's another resource you can use.

For instance [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1), has a resource to update `POST statuses/update` and one to update with media `POST statuses/update_with_media` whereas they could just use `update`, they provided a new resource that is a "specialization" of the other.

As a Developer/Consumer, I like it better like that. I don't have to mind more parameters if I don't need to. When I need to, then I just look at the doc for that resource.